# Query Pane Docking in pgAdmin3

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-3

I just started using pgAdmin3. I do not like having to have a new window when I want to run ad hoc SQL queries. Is there a way to do dock it within the top level app and actually show in the main space (to the right of the connection hierarchy view on the left)?

Comment: SuperUser seems more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do that. The only panes available in the main window are listed in the menu under View: `Object browser`, `SQL pane`, `Tool bar`.

You can ...

... select a passage in the query tool, then hit <kbd>**F5**</kbd> to execute just the selection. This way you can have various queries on a page for ad-hoc calls.

... `Copy SQL from the main window to query tool` automatically with this option.

[image]

Comment: yeah, i started using `DBeaver`.  much better

Comment: Ditto - `DBeaver` over PGAdmin for the text-resize in the Results pane alone (that's been a bug in PGAdmin since at least 2010: set a font size and the results pane rows don't respond properly, leaving you reading results that are cut off halfway up).

Answer (score 1):

Selecting `Default View` from the `View` menu reattached the floating SQL pane window. Though this isn’t exactly what you are asking, various searches for this problem led here, so maybe it will help someone.